# UIViewController Object's property not accessible

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I'm running Mac OS X Lion with xcode-4.2

In my AppDelegate.m in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method I have the following extract.

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[WSWFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WSWFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[WSWSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WSWSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
self.tabBarController = [[TabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

[self.tabBarController showSplash];

[viewController1 displayItems];
```

What I'm trying to do is access the displayItems property of the viewController1 object which is of the type WSWFirstViewController.

In WSWFirstViewController.h I have

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *displayItems;
```

In WSWFirstViewController.m I have @synthesized displayItems.

I can't seem to figure out why I get a:

Property 'displayItems' not found on object of type 'UIViewController *'.

Until I noticed my object (viewController1) wasn't of the type UIViewController * but WSWFirstViewController *. But still that didn't help me any further.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer your controllers by their proper type:

```
 WSWFirstViewController *viewController1 = [[WSWFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WSWFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
 WSWSecondViewController *viewController2 = [[WSWSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WSWSecondViewController" bundle:nil];

 ....

 [viewController1 displayItems];  // this will now work if you are in the same context
```

Comment: That's what you get from reusing generated code. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

have you declared in interface NSMutableArray displayItems?